# What LEGO set is this bag with minidoll?

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help me identify the set that these parts come from?

The bag is number two.

[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is [Heartlake Hot Air Balloon (41097)](https://brickset.com/sets/41097-1/Heartlake-Hot-Air-Balloon).

[image: Set photo]

The red striped torso only appears in a few sets, and it's fairly obvious from the rest of the parts which one this is.

Here's what that bag builds specifically:

[image: Bag 2 photo]